# How to Insert automated-fill data from the form using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Good day everyone, I currently working on form using php. 
At the moment, the **'Staff Name' in the form will automatically appear once user login** using their ID, im using this code to make it appear in the form;

```
<label>Name: </label> <strong><?php echo $row['staffname'] ?></strong>
```

However, when I click the Submit button, I checked in the database the staffname will not be stored.

What can I add to the coding to make it as a input?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: "What can I add to the coding to make it as a input?". Well, make it an input (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input). After that you can retrieve the input value in your PHP script and do whatever you need to store the new value in the database (most likely thats an sql query).

Comment: Well, you can add an additional `<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $row['staffname'] ?>' name='staffname' />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it as an input, you can use the input tag inside the form.

```
<input type="text" name="staffname" id="staffname" value="<?php echo 
$row['staffname'];?>">
```

Also please make sure you are getting value for the variable 
`$row['staffname']`

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX and jQuery to submit the data and add the label staffname like

```html
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get Staffname
  var staffname = $('label').text();
  // Get other field by ID
  var field1 = $('#field1').val();
  // or get all fields with
  var allFormData = $(this).serialize();

  $.post('save.php', {
    staffname: staffname,
    field1: field1,
  }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);  
  });
});
```

Comment: I haven't try this, I was successfully using the example below. Surely I will try this example soon. TQ